# how to connect to my local proxy via public wifi

Tags: burp

is there a way to connect to my PC proxy with burp suite, when i'm not connected to my local network ?

I wanted to use my proxy from other places.
is there a way to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean with local network? Do you have an internet connection? Does the proxy have connection to the internet? If either your PC or your Proxy don't have connection to the internet, you can't use your proxy.

Comment: i have internet connection, i have setup burp suite proxy for local use. but i want to use it whenever i'm not at home.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: programming ? no. simply use burp suite free and simple regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use openvpn. Create channel between proxy pc and your device, use vpn server address as proxy host.

Comment: hmmm. i don't understand open VPN, still trying.